# Egit Eclipse Receive Commits

Tags: java, android, eclipse, commit, egit

I am working in a team and and we are using Eclipse. We all need to be able to work on the same project through Eclipse so have installed Egit and make a git repository.

How do they get my files which I have 'committed' onto their version of Eclipse. The files are viewable in our Bitbucket account.

Thanks

Comment: add them as users on bitbucket and get them to import project from git on eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Say we all have the project on Eclipse, and one of us makes a small change. Is there a way for everyone to also see this small change on their computers by refreshing or something, instead of importing the project all over again.

Comment: see answer, http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 is a good tutorial to learn about git. most git commands are accessed in eclipse by right clicking on project and select `Team`

Answer (score 0):

add your team as users to the project on bitbucket. Then in eclipse:

> File->Import->Git->Projects from git

on the next screen select `Clone URI` since you will be pulling it from bitbucket.

On the next screen, each user will enter their credentials that can be found on bitbucket.
URI can be found on repo page for each user. eg `https://username@bitbucket.org/username/project.git`

then you just select the branch/project you want to import.

When users make a change, they can commit and push the change up to bitbucket. Other users will then have to do a `pull` to view the changes. This is done by right clicking on project and selecting:

> Team->Pull

Comment: did you get it working? consider accepting this answer by clicking the tick on the left if you found it useful.